# Excel Adding up numbers by type

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with 2 columns, the first is the description, which comes from a drop down  list and the second is the amount, for example

```
Col1   Col2
Item1  $10
Item2  $20
```

How can I add up all the Items1's and Items2's?

Comment: By making a pivot table.

Comment: Look at SUM, SUMIF, SUMIFS and pivot tables

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a Pivot Table. Use Column 1 for Rows, and use Column 2 for Values. From the Pivot Table, you can click around in each category to get more detail.

If you don't need all that detail, you could also just use the SUMIF function. As your table above is set up, it would look like this:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"Item1",B:B)
=SUMIF(A:A,"Item2",B:B)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of rows definitely use a pivot table. They are a lot of fun. Here is a tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peNTp5fuKFg